# Switch to Frame not working in HtmlUnit Driver

Tags: java, selenium, driver

I'm Working with HtmlUnit Driver, however my code works with Firefox or chrome but when I started using HtmlUnit Driver, it works to a point but after that it stuck at the line where I used the driver.switchTo().frame("Big");

I have refereed below links, but not sure why its not working

[.switchTo().frame(<'frameId'>); not working with HtmlUnit Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833114/switchto-frameframeid-not-working-with-htmlunit-driver)

https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/15309/selenium-htmlunit-how-do-i-disable-js-errors

below is what I tried.

CustomHtmlUnitDriver.java

```
    public class CustomHtmlUnitDriver extends HtmlUnitDriver {
 @Override
    protected WebClient modifyWebClient(WebClient client) {
        WebClient modifiedClient = super.modifyWebClient(client);
        modifiedClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false); // see here
        modifiedClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        return modifiedClient;
    }
}
```

Startup.java

```
  static CustomHtmlUnitDriver driver = new CustomHtmlUnitDriver();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
     ---
   /*some working  code */
   driver.switchTo().frame("Big");
  /*and then the error as below*/
```

Error as

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: Unable to locate frame with
>   name or ID: Big Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292',
>   time: '2018-06-25T15:24:21.231Z' System info: host: 'CPU-38', ip:
>   '000000', os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.2',
>   java.version: '1.8.0_171' Driver info: driver.version: unknown at
>   org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver$HtmlUnitTargetLocator.frame(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1507)

Comment: are you set javasecriptexecution true?

Answer (score 0):

Two possible reasons are coming to my mind

1. modifiedClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false); This meany you are ignoring js errors. And the HtmlUnit js support is not perfect in some ways, maybe a js function fails before this function (or one called from the function) and because of this the frame never gets created. Please check your log, maybe there is a hint.
2. The frame is created by async js; maybe you have to wait after the last working step until the frame gets created. Use waitForBackground... on your client to add some wait time.

If the frame you are looking for is part of the plain Html response (use tools like Charles to see what is really going on between you browser and the server) this might be a bug in HtmlUnit/WebDriver.

Please provide a complete working example to give us a chance to reproduce/debug the problem.